# View content of POST from an html form in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: html, google-chrome, developer-tools

After submitting a very simple form:

```
<div id='submit_div' style="display: inline-block;">
  <form id='submit_form' method='post' action="http://localhost:28130/fusion">
    <input type='text' value='{ "eventType": "person_sopId", "badgeId" : 7, "sopId": 100 }'>
    <input type='submit' value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

In `Developer toolbar | Network| Headers` there is a lot information available:

[image]

But I did not locate the `POST` body: is that available/viewable?

*Update* In response to a comment here is the entire tab

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post body is normally visible below the information you are showing inside this same tab.

It's at the bottom of the tab and appears as Form Data.

Comment: I updated the question with the full tab: I had not seen anything relevant and in particular no `Form Data` .  Am I missing something?

Comment: This helped me: turns out there is _no_ form data : see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

OK I see what happened:  I had not provided a *name* to the single *input* field. Actually i would like to submit the entire thing as an ***unnamed*** *POST* request. Not sure if that's possible from an html form.

First the *input* needs a *name* : let's add it:

```
 <input type='text' name='input_json' value='{ "eventType": "person_sopId", "badgeId" : 7, "sopId": 100 }'>
```

Now hitting *submit* results in *Form Data* viewable - per @MihailMinkov

[image]

Comment: The inputs have to have a name attribute defined in order to be sent via post. You can also use arrays if you prefer. The syntax is like: `<input ... name="info[json]">`.